# STM32F3 timers & computing

Tags: microcontroller

I have an STM32F3 discovery board. I want to go to the next step and I want to try to use timers in a few configurations.

How can I calculate variables (such as prescaler, period)? I looked in all datasheets, manuals and didn't find anything that can describe these values as  - Input capture mode, OP, PWM, etc.

I think that prescaler is for downgrading a frequency from 1-65575.

So if I have f<sub>cpu</sub>=72MHz and want to generate a signal of frequency=40kHz, am I supposed to do: 72MHz/40kHz=1800?

Now should I subtract this prescaler with -1?

Comment: I'd leave prescaler off (code bits 00) and use an Auto-Reload value of 1800 to Toggle an Output Bit at 40 KHz. (Eg see p. 75 in [STM32F3 Timers pdf](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/carbajal/Microcontrollers/SLIDES/STM32F3%20Timers.pdf) file).  (I have no hands-on experience with STM32F3 so am saying how it looks to me, vs a known solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00058181.pdf

Let's use this datasheet as an example.
Page 18 holds what is known as the clock tree. It shows with what frequency every component ticks with. So let's try following it.
You have your crystal oscillator working on some frequency (or some internal clock). You multiply it by PLL multiplication factor. PLL is used to make a higher frequency signal from a lower one. You then divide by AHB prescaler. You then divide by APB1 or APB2 prescaler (depending on which timer you're using) and then multiply by 2 if APB prescaler is something other than 1. What we have now is the clock timer module "sees". Now it divides that clock with timer prescaler and it increments (or decrements) the counter with that frequency. Once it reaches a set point it will throw the interrupt.

AHB and APB registers are usually set in the project settings of your programming environment. For timer prescaler register refer to the datasheet of your MCU.